# Trying to do linear algebra with IronPython

Tags: python, linear-algebra, ironpython, mathematical-optimization

With CPython i would use numpy.linalg for linear algebra (svd) calculation, but numpy doesn't work with IronPython (i got import error with multiarray module).
IronPython is mandatory, because i use a software with an embedded IronPython.

I can't find on the internet a functionnal library for IronPython... Somebody know a good library with few dependencies for IronPython and ideally for Windows and Linux ??

In reality, my goal is to find a middle plane from a set of points. I found this code on internet:

```
def planeFit(points):
    """
    p, n = planeFit(points)

    Given an array, points, of shape (d,...)
    representing points in d-dimensional space,
    fit an d-dimensional plane to the points.

    Return a point, p, on the plane (the point-cloud centroid),
    and the normal, n.
    """
    import numpy as np
    from numpy.linalg import svd
    points = np.reshape(points, (np.shape(points)[0], -1))  # Collapse trialing dimensions
    assert points.shape[0] <= points.shape[1], "There are only %s points in %s dimensions." % (points.shape[1], points.shape[0])
    ctr = points.mean(axis=1)
    x = points - ctr[:, np.newaxis]
    M = np.dot(x, x.T)  # Could also use np.cov(x) here.
    return ctr, svd(M)[0][:,1]
```